# Overloading constructors with @autowire annotation in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

How to add a new overloading constructor in spring boot with `@autowire` annotation?

The current state of the class which is already made public

```
@Component
public class PersonDetails {

    private Address address;


    @Autowired
    public PersonDetails(Address address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public void printDetails() {
        System.out.println(address.toString() + " " + bankAccount.toString());
    }
}
```

Now BankAccount details should be added like this

```
@Component
public class PersonDetails {

    private Address address;
    private BankAccount bankAccount;

    @Autowired
    public PersonDetails(Address address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    @Autowired
    public PersonDetails(Address address, BankAccount bankAccount) {
        System.out.println("Another constructor where required is true by default");
        this.address = address;
        this.bankAccount = bankAccount;
    }

    public void printDetails() {
        System.out.println(address.toString() + " " + bankAccount.toString());
    }
}
```

The problem is spring won't allow overloading constructor `@autowire` annotations.

How to add overloading constructors with `@autowire` annotation (or any other way) in spring boot projects with backward compatibility?

It can be done with field-level `@autowire` annotation(hopefully a better way since field level `@autowire` annotations are not recommended in spring boot) unless there is no better way.

Comment: This looks like a class that shouldn't have any autowiring in the first place!. You shold use autowiring for your application components, this looks like a DTO being shoehorned into using autowiring.

Answer (score 0):

According to Spring, you should only `@Autowired` a constructor if it is not obvious for Spring, which constructor it should use.

Spring will use the constructor with the most arguments that can be matched with Spring beans. If there are two constructors with equal size of arguments that can be matched, Spring needs the `@Autowired`.

Regarding *backwards compatibility*:

Just remove both `@Autowired` annotations.

If a deprecated application uses your `PersonDetails` class, it will use the `1st` constructor, as only one bean can be injected.

If a up-to-date application uses your `PersonDetails` class, it will use the `2nd` constructor, as it will be able to inject both beans.

Take a look at Spring Framework in general: [Constructor-based Dependency Injection](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.2.2.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-constructor-injection)

And especially: [Spring Beans and Dependency Injection](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.2.2.RELEASE/reference/html/using-spring-boot.html#using-boot-spring-beans-and-dependency-injection)

Comment: Though technically solves the problem, client test cases need to be updated since a new parameter is introduced. I appreciate your time.

Comment: I've updated my answer, maybe this helps you a bit.